# Abstract Singleton pattern class

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I'm trying to achieve the following goal:

Using this general singleton class:

```
abstract class Singleton {

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function self()
    {
      if(self::$instance == null)
      {   
         $c = __CLASS__;
         self::$instance = new $c;
      }

      return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

I'd love to be able to create Singleton concrete class such as:

```
class Registry extends Singleton {
    private function __construct() {}
    ...
}
```

and then use them as:

```
Registry::self()->myAwesomePonyRelatedMethod();
```

But obliviously `__CLASS__` is intended as `Singleton` so a fatal error occurs about PHP not being able to instantiate an abstract class. But the truth is that I want Registry (for example) to be instantiated.

So I tried with `get_class($this)` but being a static class, Singleton has no $this.

What could I do to make it work?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: [Singletons are Evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abridged code from my Slides [Singletons in PHP - Why they are bad and how you can eliminate them from your applications](http://www.slideshare.net/go_oh/singletons-in-php-why-they-are-bad-and-how-you-can-eliminate-them-from-your-applications):

```
abstract class Singleton
{
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        return isset(static::$instance)
            ? static::$instance
            : static::$instance = new static();
    }

    final private function __construct()
    {
        static::init();
    }

    final public function __clone() {
        throw new Exception('Not Allowed');
    }

    final public function __wakeup() {
        throw new Exception('Not Allowed');
    }

    protected function init()
    {}
}
```

Then you can do

```
class A extends Singleton
{
    protected static $instance;
}
```

If you need to do additional setup logic override `init` in the extending class.

Also see [Is there a use-case for singletons with database access in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323)

Comment: @Gordon, you have just destroyed my project idea. How cruel! I loved Singleton before, and now I read all this bad things about them :(. So basically to avoid them I should use dependency injection pattern?

Comment: @JeffPigarelli I'd say sorry if I wouldn't consider this a major WIN ;) Yes. Dependency Injection is the way to go. And separation of creator graphs and collaborator graphs. See http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/21/where-have-all-the-singletons-gone/